# ORDER group_concat using WHERE IN values

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query

```
SELECT cibor_users.ID, 
    cibor_users.display_name,
    cibor_users.user_email,
    cibor_users.user_url,
GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value) AS customer_address
FROM cibor_users 
   JOIN cibor_usermeta  ON cibor_users.ID = cibor_usermeta.user_id
WHERE cibor_usermeta.meta_key IN ('paupress_address_one_1','paupress_address_city_1','paupress_address_state_1','paupress_address_postal_code_1','telephone','user_type','primary_business','realtor_designation')
GROUP BY cibor_usermeta.user_id
```

The information is then displayed in a table using:

```
<td ><?php echo $row['display_name'];?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row['user_url'];?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row['user_email'];?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row['customer_address'];?></td>
```

The problem is that the values in the "WHERE" statement are displayed randomly and inconsistently. So I added an ORDER BY statement:

```
SELECT cibor_users.ID, 
    cibor_users.display_name,
    cibor_users.user_email,
    cibor_users.user_url,
GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value ORDER BY meta_value ASC SEPARATOR ' ') AS customer_address
FROM cibor_users 
    JOIN cibor_usermeta  ON cibor_users.ID = cibor_usermeta.user_id
WHERE cibor_usermeta.meta_key IN ('paupress_address_one_1','paupress_address_city_1','paupress_address_state_1','paupress_address_postal_code_1','telephone','user_type','primary_business','realtor_designation')
GROUP BY cibor_usermeta.user_id
```

However, this alphabetized the information I needed for the "Customer_Address." And I need the information displayed in the same order as they are placed in the "WHERE" statement.

I tried using ORDER BY FIELD

```
WHERE cibor_usermeta.meta_key IN ('paupress_address_one_1','paupress_address_city_1','paupress_address_state_1','paupress_address_postal_code_1','telephone','user_type','primary_business','realtor_designation')
ORDER BY FIELD (cibor_usermeta.meta_key, ['paupress_address_one_1','paupress_address_city_1','paupress_address_state_1','paupress_address_postal_code_1','telephone','user_type','primary_business','realtor_designation'])
GROUP BY cibor_usermeta.user_id
```

Is there a way to specify the exact order of the concatenated information based on the WHERE IN statement?

Comment: Great question, carefully written, etc. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to do a case when in your order clause

```
group_concat(meta_value 
            order by
             case meta_key when 'paupress_adress_one1' then 0
                           when 'paupress_address_city_1' then 1
                           when 'paupress_address_state_1' then 2
                           --etc.
             end
             separator ' ')
```